# Set user role attribute based on signup location in rails 4 with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm trying to come up with a way to securely set user roles based on signup location.  For example, two such roles would be a customer and a seller.  I would like a user's role to be set to a seller if they sign up from the home page, but a customer if they sign up during purchasing or when visiting a seller's page.

With rails 4 and strong parameters, I definitely do not want to permit the user role attribute, as anyone could then maliciously set their role attribute to admin (a security vulnerability).  This prevents the role attribute from being set anywhere other than inside the users_controller, which prevents the role from being set based on signup location.  It seems to be a catch-22.

I don't want to use a hidden field, because that would be insecure for something as important as user role.  I'm just kind of at a loss for how to handle this.  I am not using devise or cancan, but I'm not sure if those would contain a solution (cancan doesn't even seem to be compatible with rails 4 yet anyways).  I'm also not sure if it would be in my best interest to maybe break apart sellers and customers into completely different models.  I would prefer to avoid this if I could.

Any suggestions or even just a direction to look into would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas come to mind:

- Inspect the request in the controller, and assign user type based on where the submission came from
- Have a customer signup form include a referral ID of sorts, from the seller's page, included in the form (hidden field), and key off that
- Submit the customer and seller forms to entirely different routes, so it's obvious